# Initializing 2D ArrayList for for-loop summation (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to sum N pairs of ints--an Nx2 ArrayList--and return the N summations as an ArrayList. While I understand it is not necessary to set up a class to accomplish this, I would like to do so as practice for future projects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SumsInLoop {
    public SumsInLoop(int numberOfPairs, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> numbersList) {}

    public ArrayList<Integer> getSums(int numberOfPairs, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> numbersList) {
        ArrayList<Integer> pairsOfSums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (ArrayList<Integer> Pair : numbersList) {
            int x = Pair.get(0);
            int y = Pair.get(1);
            int sum = x + y;
            pairsOfSums.add(sum);
        }
        System.out.println(pairsOfSums);
        return pairsOfSums;
    }
```

The data that I am given is a random assortment of N pairs (numbersOfPairs) of integers, e.g. 612673 108695. I would like to add these pairs of integers to a 2D ArrayList (numbersList) that will be called by getSums.

However, I am having difficulties initializing numbersList. My main function is as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myNumberOfPairs = 13;
        ArrayList[][] myNumbersList = new ArrayList[13][2];
        myNumbersList[0][0] = new ArrayList<>();
        myNumbersList[0][0].add(612673);
        myNumbersList[0][1].add(108695);
        myNumbersList[1][0] = new ArrayList<>();
        myNumbersList[1][0].add(756875);
        myNumbersList[1][1].add(496058);
        SumsInLoop mySum = new SumsInLoop(myNumberOfPairs,myNumbersList);
        mySum.getSums(myNumberOfPairs, myNumbersList);
```

The last two lines of code throw errors, asking me to change myNumbersList to type `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` which throws even more errors, even after changing all 2D ArrayLists to type `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`.

So, my two questions are as follows:

1. How can I initialize an NxM ArrayList and populate it correctly?
2. Is there a faster way of accomplishing this task while still using a class method?

P.S. I'm used to coding in Python and am self-teaching myself Java, so any other information or resources you can provide me with are much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you want to use an `ArrayList` instead of a normal array?

Comment: Can I still specify parameters in a normal array? If so, then no.

Comment: What you might want to look into - which might be better suited for what you want to do - is to create a `Pair` class which would just store two values, and then make your function accept an array of `Pair`s i.e. `Pair[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to simplify your input by using 2D array of `int` : `int[][] myNumbersList = new int[13][2];`
The expected output in that case is a 1D array of `int[13]` that can be obtained as follows (demonstrated with 2 pairs. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ) :

```
public class SumsInLoop {
    //pairsOfInts should be an [n][2] array
    private static int[] sumOfPairs(int[][] pairsOfInts) {

        int[] sums = new int[pairsOfInts.length];
        for(int pairIndex = 0; pairIndex < pairsOfInts.length; pairIndex++) {
            sums[pairIndex]= pairsOfInts[pairIndex][0]+pairsOfInts[pairIndex][1];
        }
        return sums;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfPairs = 2;
        int[][] pairsOfInts = new int[numberOfPairs][2];
        pairsOfInts[0] = new int[] {612673,108695 };
        pairsOfInts[1] = new int[] {756875,496058 };
        int[] sumOfPairs = sumOfPairs(pairsOfInts);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumOfPairs));
    }
}
```

If you want a solution implemented with `List` you can make use of javafx [Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) (or make your own pair class.
The input can be defined as `List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> pairsOfInts = new ArrayList<>();` 
The out put can be an array as above, or a `List<Integer>`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class SumsInLoop {

    private static List<Integer> sumOfPairs(List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairsOfInts) {
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Pair<Integer,Integer> pair : pairsOfInts) {
            sums.add(pair.getKey()+ pair.getValue());
        }
        return sums;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> pairsOfInts = new ArrayList<>();
        pairsOfInts.add (new Pair<>(612673,108695 ));
        pairsOfInts.add (new Pair<>(756875,496058));
        List<Integer> sumOfPairs = sumOfPairs(pairsOfInts);
        System.out.println(sumOfPairs); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The (compile) exception you are getting is due to the fact that you expect a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, but pass an `ArrayList[][]`. (which is not the same in Java)

1. In your case you'd need (in the `main` method):

   ```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myNumbersList = new ArrayList</* when java > 6 ;)*/>(13);
   ```

   this only sets the capacity of the (parent) list (..and the underlying/internal backing array)
   to initialize the child lists, you'd not come around looping (somehow...even not in python :):

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
       myNumbersList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(2));
   }
   ```

   Depends on what means "correctly" ...but I assume with "random data", ideally you would again inner loop:

   ```
   java.util.Random rnd = new Random(/*seed default current timestamp*/);
   //...
   for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
     ArrayList<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<>(2);
     for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
       innerList.add(rnd.netxInt(/*bound default Integer.MAX_VALUE*/) /*+/-/% offset*/);
     }
     myNumberList.add(innerList);
   }
   ```
2. Sorry I am not aware of one (faster way), but much depends on the "input format".

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the amount of values in a pair, an `ArrayList` is unnecessary. You can create your own, simpler implementation of a pair.

```
class Pair {
    public final int left;
    public final int right;

    public Pair(int left, int right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

You can then access the values by creating a pair object and accessing its fields.

```
Pair p = new Pair(10, 7);
System.out.println(p.left); // 10
System.out.println(p.right); // 7
```

---

You can then more easily redefine your `getSums` method.

```
public static List<Integer> getSums(List<Pair> pairs){
    List<Integer> pairsOfSums = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Pair pair : pairs){
        int sum = pair.left + pair.right;
        pairsOfSums.add(sum);
    }
    return pairsOfSums;
}
```

Please also notice the function can be `static` and you don't need to pass the number of pairs. The `for-each` loop will cycle through all of them regardless.

---

Initializing the array is then easier than the method you have described in the question.

```
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new Pair(7, 10));
pairs.add(new Pair(18, 3));
pairs.add(new Pair(-6, 0));
pairs.add(new Pair(4, 2));
System.out.println(SumsInLoop.getSums(pairs));
```